# Having MySQL error #1242

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1242

Problem is to deduct 1% service charge from saving account balance that have both loan and saving account.

**Schema is**

"branch" table(branch_name, branch_city, assets)

"customer" table(customer_name, customer_street, customer_city)

"account" table (account_number, branch_name, balance)

"loan"table (loan_number, branch_name, amount)

"depositor"table (customer_name, account_number)

"borrower" table (customer_name, loan_number)

**I tried with this:**

```
update account
-> set balance=balance*0.99

-> where (select distinct customer_name from 

->borrower where customer_name in(select 

->customer_name from depositor));
```

but getting error 1242. can someone help me with this?

Comment: Format your code,it can not be read now!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [help with subquery! returns more than 1 row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419094/help-with-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row)

Answer (score 0):

Table account doesn't have any references to customer_name.

Try like this

```
update account set balance=balance*99 where account_number in (select account_number from depositor);
```

Comment: Sorry I need to deduct 1% for those who have both loan and and saving account. But this solution doesn't checks that. It only deducts for those who have saving account.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the INNER JOIN instead of where clause.

```
update account
-> set balance=balance*0.99

-> where (select distinct borrower.customer_name from 

->borrower INNER JOIN depositor  ON borrower.customer_name = depositor.customer_name));
```

Comment: Customer_name is not present in account that's why it is getting a error 1054.

Comment: can you please remove it and execute

Comment: I tried that but got error again this time error 1052

Comment: Sorry now its showing the same error that I was originally facing